# Убрать все метки в гугл картах

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть карта гугл на сайте. И на ней, при увеличении или уменьшении масштаба, отображаются рядом с моей меткой, метки различных компаний. Возможно ли сделать так, чтоб отображалась лишь моя метка?